# How to use SharePoint 2010 REST api to update column values?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, metadata

I just found the REST API for SharePoint 2010. I'm trying to use cURL to call the API to update empty columns. I've managed to use the links below to access various information for my company's test site.

- http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc
- http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TestDocLibrary
- http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata

But I'm still confused as to how to use it to get it to update a column "Title". I'm also testing this out with an application called POSTMAN to see if I can get it to update through the REST API. Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the request as a POST (with MERGE in the header) with the updated data in the header.

See the second answer here (the first is for 2013): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820779/sharepoint-2010-rest-api-jquery-insert-update-delete

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I've managed to use the "Get" to fetch the specific document I'm interested in to get the media_etag (the numbers with the curly brackets? {#########}) which I presume is used for the if-match: etag. 

When trying to use the "POST" with Headers: "X-HTTP-Method : MERGE" where do I put the XML data for the title?

<d:Title m:null="true">TEST1</d:Title>

Comment: Add the XML to the "data" being sent. In the example in the link above, this would be the "data:" line. They are sending JSON there, but you might be sending an XML string. Something like: contentType: "application/xml", data: "your XML"

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got it to work in POSTMAN and was able to replicate it in cURL to get it to work!